# Container view is getting hidden under Right Navigation Bar button Item,SWIFT iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

As per previously implemented code there is a navigation bar with static Image (A bell icon) on top of this is a **Custom container view** with a **label** has been added to show the notifications which are dynamic.

Issue is that the container view is going behind the right navigation item i.e. bell image as per the following screenshot:

[image]

Idealy the required UI behavior is that orange container view with label should come in the front.

```
self.view.bringSubview(toFront:myCustomView)
```

The above code is not working.

Comment: Can Some one please help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a Solution. I made the nav bar item's background color clear and on top of that added my container view. Now its working fine